Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DeliveryMethods" - .NET CORE - EF CORE
I'm having a problem saving orders, in the service responsible for this task it calls the await _unitOfWork.Repository().AddAsync(order) method.
Then the saving process begins in the database, but when saving the error returns.
The strange thing is that I am never saving the deliveryMethod in the database, I am only saving the order, and the same method works for other entities, but it is returning an error while I am saving the order.
I have no idea where I'm going wrong if anyone could give me a piece of advice of how can I make correct this.
OrderService
using Domain.Entities;
using Domain.Entities.OrderAggregate;
using Domain.Interfaces;
using Domain.Specifications;

namespace Infrastructure.Services;

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private readonly ICartRepository _cartRepo;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IStockMovimentService _movimentService;

    public OrderService(ICartRepository cartRepo, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IStockMovimentService movimentService)
    {
        _cartRepo = cartRepo;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _movimentService = movimentService;
    }

        
    public async Task<Order> CreateOrderAsync(string buyerEmail, 
        int deliveryMethodId, string cartId, Address ShippingAddress)
    {
        var cart = await _cartRepo.GetCartAsync(cartId);

        var items = new List<OrderItem>();
        foreach(var item in cart.Items)
        {
            var productItem = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().GetByIdAsync(item.Id);

            var itemOrdered = new ProductItemOrdered(productItem.Id, 
                productItem.Name, productItem.PictureUrl);
            var orderItem = new OrderItem(itemOrdered, productItem.Price, item.Quantity, item.Size);
            items.Add(orderItem);
            await _movimentService.OutgoingStockMovimentService(productItem, item.Size, item.Quantity);
        }

        var dm = await _unitOfWork.Repository<DeliveryMethod>().GetByIdAsync(deliveryMethodId);

        var subtotal = items.Sum(item => item.Price * item.Quantity);

        var spec = new OrderByPaymentIntentIdSpecification(cart.PaymentIntentId);
        var order = await _unitOfWork.Repository<Order>().GetEntityWithSpecification(spec);

        if(order is not null)
        {
            order.ShipToAddress = ShippingAddress;
            order.DeliveryMethod = dm;
            order.Subtotal = subtotal;
            await _unitOfWork.Repository<Order>().UpdateAsync(order);
        }
        else
        {
            order = new Order(items,buyerEmail,ShippingAddress,dm,subtotal,cart.PaymentIntentId);
            await _unitOfWork.Repository<Order>().AddAsync(order);
        }


        var result = await _unitOfWork.Complete();


        if (result <= 0) return null;

        return order;
    }


Order Entity:
using Domain.Enums;

namespace Domain.Entities.OrderAggregate;

public class Order : BaseEntity
{

    public string BuyerEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public Address ShipToAddress { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryMethodId { get; set; }
    public DeliveryMethod DeliveryMethod { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; } = OrderStatus.Pending;
    public string PaymentIntentId { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
    }

    public Order(IReadOnlyList<OrderItem> orderItems, string buyerEmail, Address shipToAddress, 
        DeliveryMethod deliveryMethod, decimal subtotal, string paymentIntentId)
    {
        BuyerEmail = buyerEmail;
        ShipToAddress = shipToAddress;
        DeliveryMethod = deliveryMethod;
        OrderItems = orderItems;
        Subtotal = subtotal;
        PaymentIntentId = paymentIntentId;
    }

    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        return Subtotal + DeliveryMethod.Price;
    }
}


Generic repository and UnitOfWork
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<StoreDbContext> _contextFactory;

        public GenericRepository(IDbContextFactory<StoreDbContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
        {
            using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            await context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
....

using Domain.Entities;
using Domain.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections;

namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<StoreDbContext> _contextFactory;
        private Hashtable _repositories;

        public UnitOfWork(IDbContextFactory<StoreDbContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // No need to dispose DbContext as it's handled by the factory
        }

        public IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
        {
            if (_repositories is null) _repositories = new Hashtable();

            var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

            if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>);
                var repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(
                            repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _contextFactory);

                _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
            }

            return (IGenericRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
        }

        public async Task<int> Complete()
        {
            using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}


the code returns the following error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Infrastructure.Data.StoreDbContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DeliveryMethods"

      DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        Exception data:
          Severity: ERROR
          SqlState: 23505
          MessageText: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DeliveryMethods"
          Detail: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
          SchemaName: public
          TableName: DeliveryMethods
          ConstraintName: PK_DeliveryMethods
          File: nbtinsert.c
          Line: 671
          Routine: _bt_check_unique
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DeliveryMethods"

      DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
         at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        Exception data:
          Severity: ERROR
          SqlState: 23505
          MessageText: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_DeliveryMethods"
          Detail: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
          SchemaName: public
          TableName: DeliveryMethods
          ConstraintName: PK_DeliveryMethods
          File: nbtinsert.c
          Line: 671
          Routine: _bt_check_unique
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.

First I think that might be something in database in orders table but it's empty.
-- Debuging:
enter image description here
-- Orders Table:
enter image description here
-- StoreContext
using System.Reflection;
using Domain.Entities;
using Domain.Entities.OrderAggregate;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infrastructure.Data;

public class StoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<StoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductUnit> ProductUnits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeliveryMethod> DeliveryMethods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductMovimentHistory> ProductMovimentHistory { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}

I try debuging it but I can't find what I made wrong.
If anyone could help me to find it would be great.

I Found the issue, it occurs becouse I'm mapping the entity itself so the entity framework understands that it needs to be inserted as a new entity, so I changed the contructor saving the Id of the entity instead so then the entity framework understands that it is a reference and not an insertion.

I Found the issue, it occurs becouse I'm mapping the entity itself so the entity framework understands that it needs to be inserted as a new entity, so I changed the contructor saving the Id of the entity instead so then the entity framework understands that it is a reference and not an insertion.
How the order entity will be after the changes:
using Domain.Enums;

namespace Domain.Entities.OrderAggregate;

public class Order : BaseEntity
{

    public string BuyerEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public Address ShipToAddress { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryMethodId { get; set; }
    public DeliveryMethod DeliveryMethod { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; } = OrderStatus.Pending;
    public string PaymentIntentId { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
    }

    public Order(IReadOnlyList<OrderItem> orderItems, string buyerEmail, Address shipToAddress, 
        DeliveryMethod deliveryMethod, decimal subtotal, string paymentIntentId)
    {
        BuyerEmail = buyerEmail;
        ShipToAddress = shipToAddress;
        DeliveryMethodId = deliveryMethod.Id;
        OrderItems = orderItems;
        Subtotal = subtotal;
        PaymentIntentId = paymentIntentId;
    }

    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        return Subtotal + DeliveryMethod.Price;
    }
}


